# Insert from more than one table, depending on conditions

Tags: sql

please help me.

I'm trying to Insert into form 2 different table depending in condition and getting error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

```
 INSERT INTO Table_1 (col1, col2, col3)
     CASE WHEN @var = 'L' THEN 
        SELECT FROM Table_2 col1, col2, col3
     WHEN @var = 'S' THEN 
        SELECT FROM Table_3 col1, col2, col3
    END
```

What is wrong with statement?
Is that even possible?
Thanks.

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL (assuming this is T-SQL/SQL Server) is **not** equivalent to `switch/case` in C# - it **cannot** be used as a flow control statement to handle code. `CASE` in T-SQL is merely an **expression** that returns a single atomic value, based on conditions. For flow control in T-SQL, you need to use `IF` statement

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `if-else`. As marc_s has said `case` is not the same as `switch` and is not used for control flow in `sql`

```
IF @var='L'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl ( c1, c2, c3 )
    SELECT c1, c2, c3
    FROM tbla
END
ELSE IF @var='S'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl ( c1, c2, c3 )
    SELECT c1, c2, c3
    FROM tblb
END
```

If you'd like to do this as one statement then you could I believe use a `UNION ALL`

```
INSERT INTO tbl ( c1, c2, c3 )
SELECT c1, c2, c3
FROM tbla
WHERE (@var='L')
UNION ALL
SELECT c1, c2, c3
FROM tblb
WHERE (@var='S')
```

Though I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

That's not valid TSQL. This might work instead:

```
IF @var = 'L'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table_1 (col1, col2, col3)
    SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM Table_2 
END

IF @var = 'S'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table_1 (col1, col2, col3)
    SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM Table_3 
END
```

Comment: there is no `THEN` at the end of the 'boolean expression' of an [`IF`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx) statement in T-SQL

Comment: Nice catch, thanks! I just moved the code around a bit and forgot that step.